# Number of BST with duplicated keys

Tags: algorithm, math, tree, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming

If there are n vertex with distinct keys than the number of BST given by [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). But if some elements are duplicated how we can count the number of BST?

My naive idea that if we have k equal elements among n, than we should divide Catalan number on k!(permutations of k elements). But if we check it on simplest example(BST build on [1, 1, 1]), we realize that it's wrong idea.

So how we should take into account duplicated keys when we count number of BST?

**What is BST in my question:** binary tree where all keys in left child less than in root and in right child all keys grater or equal than in root.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicated keys don't make any difference to the number of distinct trees. Each tree has a distinct shape, so you don't even need the keys to differentiate them.  You could remove the keys altogether and the trees would still all be different.

Try it with your simple example: [1,1,1].  You can still make the 5 distinct BSTs with these keys:

```
    1      1      1      1      1  
   /      /      / \      \      \
  1      1      1   1      1      1
 /        \               /        \
1          1             1          1
```

EDIT for new requirements:

If the left children must be strictly less than their parents, then duplicate keys form a linked list that works like a single node, since you can't have any left children in it.  The whole list of equal values will have only one shape, one left child and one right child:

```
    1
   / \
  0   1
       \
        1
         \
          2
```

So in this case you can just subtract the number of duplicate keys.

For N keys with M duplicates, i.e., N-M unique keys, there are Catalan(N-M) ways to make the tree.

Comment: I think I forgot to notice that under BST I mean such binary tree where all keys in left child less than in root and in right child all keys grater or equal.
And in this sence [1,1,1] generate only one tree.